# Send Data From Javafx made form to HTTP POST Request

Tags: java, javafx

I have made a form using Javafx Scene Builder 2.0 I have the form working and have variables set to the form element values. I also created a PHP script that receives post data and inserts the data into a database.

I need some help on actually sending the javafx form data via http post to my php script.

Here is my java code so far.

Main.java

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Orbis Cob Submit");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 800, 600));
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**Controller.java**

```
package sample;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import java.io.IOException;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Observable;

public class Controller {
    //Send Vars
    private String sendDataType;
    private String sendCobTarget;
    private String sendVendor;
    private String sendCobName;
    private String sendDealerID;
    private String sendJobType;
    private String sendStartDate;
    private String sendEndDate;
    private String sendAmount;
    private String sendCost;
    private String sendDataDescription;
    private DataBase db = new DataBase();

    //Data list for drop downs
    ObservableList<String> dataTypeList = FXCollections.observableArrayList("BK", "BR", "DB", "DEQ", "FI", "MB", "OB", "SAT", "SURN");
    ObservableList<String> cobTargetList = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Sales", "Services", "Both");
    ObservableList<String> vendorList = FXCollections.observableArrayList("SJO", "OCZ","Inhouse");
    ObservableList<String> jobTypeList = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Mail", "Digital");

    //Form Elements
    @FXML
    public ChoiceBox dataType;

    @FXML
    public ChoiceBox cobTarget;

    @FXML
    public ChoiceBox vendor;

    @FXML
    public Button button;

    @FXML
    public Text message;

    @FXML
    public TextField cobName;

    @FXML
    public TextField dealerID;

    @FXML
    public ChoiceBox jobType;

    @FXML
    public DatePicker startDate;

    @FXML
    public DatePicker endDate;

    @FXML
    public TextField sentAmount;

    @FXML
    public TextField cost;

    @FXML
    public TextField dataDescription;


    @FXML
    private  void initialize(){
        dataType.setItems(dataTypeList);
        cobTarget.setItems(cobTargetList);
        vendor.setItems(vendorList);
        jobType.setItems(jobTypeList);

         button.setOnAction(e -> {
             this.sendDataType = dataType.getValue().toString();
             this.sendCobTarget = cobTarget.getValue().toString();
             this.sendVendor = vendor.getValue().toString();
             this.sendCobName = cobName.getText();
             this.sendDealerID = dealerID.getText();
             this.sendJobType = jobType.getValue().toString();
             this.sendStartDate = startDate.getValue().toString();
             this.sendEndDate = endDate.getValue().toString();
             this.sendAmount = sentAmount.getText();
             this.sendCost = cost.getText();
             this.sendDataDescription = dataDescription.getText();

            //Send Field Data to HTTP POST REQUEST

        });
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to use a library like [unirest](/questions/tagged/unirest), which make sending HTTP(S) requests easier.

You use it like this:

```
Unirest.post("http://httpbin.org/post")
    .field("sendDataType", dataType.getValue().toString())
    .field("sendCobTarget", cobTarget.getValue().toString())
    .field("sendDataType", dataType.getValue().toString())
    .field("sendCobTarget", cobTarget.getValue().toString())
    .field("sendVendor", vendor.getValue().toString())
    .field("sendCobName", cobName.getText())
    .field("sendDealerID", dealerID.getText())
    .field("sendJobType", jobType.getValue().toString())
    .field("sendStartDate", startDate.getValue().toString())
    .field("sendEndDate", endDate.getValue().toString())
    .field("sendAmount", sentAmount.getText())
    .field("sendCost", cost.getText())
    .field("sendDataDescription", dataDescription.getText())
    .asJson();
```

You'd need to set each of your fields to the value you want to send.

Comment: Apart from the shortening to not send all the fields in the question, is there anything else I did wrong?

Comment: Expanded to include all fields, in case that was the issue with my answer

Comment: How to get response?